# How to refresh code lenses in monaco editor

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I adding custom CodeLenseProvider to my React Monaco Editor, which works great in general:

```js
{
    provideCodeLenses(model: monaco.editor.ITextModel, token: monaco.CancellationToken): monaco.languages.ProviderResult<monaco.languages.CodeLensList> {
      const lenses: monaco.languages.CodeLens[] = [];
      lenses.push(...getLenses());
      return {
        lenses,
        dispose: () => {},
      };
    },
  }
```

The problem is that my method `getLenses` is time consuming and asynchronous. Ideally I'd like to e.g. fetch some data when `provideCodeLenses` is called, or even better, I'd like to  be able to call `provideCodeLenses` manually refresh the lenses.

The steps would be:

- I have `onChange` listetener on

```
<MonacoEditor onChange={onChange} .../>
```

- this `onChange` is doing some async action
- once the action is finished, I'd like to refresh code lenses

How can I achieve that? I know code lense provider has `onDidChange` property but it is not really clear to me how to use it or if it helps my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By exploring `codelensController.js` to schedule code lens update manually, you have to use `onDidChange` function that will be called once during initialization of the provider with the argument being a function which can be called to signal for the update.

```
let scheduleCodeLensUpdate: () => void;

languages.registerCodeLensProvider("[language]", {
        onDidChange(cb) {
            // types are incorrect, the function doesn't actually take any arguments
            scheduleCodeLensUpdate = cb as any;

            return {
                dispose() {}
            }
        },
        provideCodeLenses(model, token) { /*...*/ }
}

// do something

// trigger code lens update
scheduleCodeLensUpdate();
```